# How to group elements by id in xslt using for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to XSLT and XPATH, I have below xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Levels>
  <Level id="1">com</Level>
  <Level id="2">bitstew</Level>
  <Level id="3">data</Level>
  <Level id="4">activity_plan</Level>
  <File id="activity_plan">ActivityPlanToDailyPlan.xml</File>
  <Level id="1">com</Level>
  <Level id="2">bitstew</Level>
  <Level id="3">director-services</Level>
  <Level id="4">manage</Level>
  <Level id="5">adapters</Level>
  <File id="adapters">Adapters.xml</File>
  <Level id="1">com</Level>
  <Level id="2">bitstew</Level>
  <Level id="3">director-services</Level>
  <Level id="4">manage</Level>
  <Level id="5">adapters</Level>
  <File id="adapters">Adapters_DELETE.xml</File>
  <Level id="1">com</Level>
  <Level id="2">bitstew</Level>
  <Level id="3">director-services</Level>
  <Level id="4">manage</Level>
  <Level id="5">adapters</Level>
  <File id="adapters">Adapters_GET.xml</File>
  <Level id="1">com</Level>
  <Level id="2">bitstew</Level>
  <Level id="3">director-services</Level>
  <Level id="4">manage</Level>
  <Level id="5">adapters</Level>
  <File id="adapters">Adapters_POST.xml</File>
  <Level id="1">com</Level>
  <Level id="2">bitstew</Level>
  <Level id="3">director-services</Level>
  <Level id="4">manage</Level>
  <Level id="5">adapters</Level>
  <File id="adapters">Adapters_PUT.xml</File>
  <Level id="1">com</Level>
  <Level id="2">griddirector</Level>
  <Level id="3">director</Level>
  <Level id="4">services</Level>
  <Level id="5">advanced_search_results</Level>
  <File id="advanced_search_results">advanced_search_results.xml</File>
  <Level id="1">com</Level>
  <Level id="2">bitstew</Level>
  <Level id="3">adk</Level>
  <Level id="4">lib</Level>
  <Level id="5">general_aggregations</Level>
  <File id="general_aggregations">aggnode.xml</File>
</Levels>
```

I want to group elements by their id, using xslt for-each, which I can use as tree like structure (left menu).

Desired output as:

```
<com>
    <bitstew>
        <data>
            <activity_plan>
                <file>ActivityPlanToDailyPlan.xml<file>
            </activity_plan>
        </data>
        <director-services>
            <manage>
                <adapters>
                    <file>Adapters.xml</file>
                    <file>Adapters_DELETE.xml</file>
                    <file>Adapters_GET.xml</file>
                    <file>Adapters_POST.xml</file>
                    <file>Adapters_PUT.xml</file>
                </adapters>
            </manage>
        </director-services>
        <adk>
            <lib>
                <general_aggregations>
                    <file>aggnode.xml</file>
                </general_aggregations>
            </lib>
        </adk>
    </bitstew>
    <griddirector>
        <director>
            <services>
                <advanced_search_results>
                    <file>advanced_search_results.xml</file>
                </advanced_search_results>
            </services>
        </director>
    </griddirector>
</com>
```

I am restricted from using `<xsl:apply-template>`, `<xsl:template>`, and `<xsl:for-each-group>` statements.  I do not know how to build using `<xsl:for-each>`.

Any help would be highly appreciated... Thanks!!!

Comment: This is confusing: can you or can you not use  use `xsl:for-each-group`? IOW, do you have an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: Thanks for reply michael, I cannot use <xsl:for-each-group>, <xsl-template> and <xsl-apply-template>... because we are using custom xslt 2.0 implementation in our project

Comment: Then you are not using XSLT. I am afraid I don't know what to recommend, because I don't know what will work in your processor. See if Muenchian grouping can work for you: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I can use <xsl:for-each> but not <xsl:for-each-group>

Comment: Are you really sure you can't use `xsl:template`? Without at least one `xsl:template` then XSLT's built-in templates apply, which just output the text. You need to double-check you are actually using XSLT here, and not some bespoke version that isn't really XSLT. Thanks.

Comment: all our xml files already had <mix:template> (which is same as <xsl:template> tag) hence no other <mix:template> tags permitted...

Answer (score 0):

Your task could be resolved via correct usage of `<xsl:variable />`.

I've done simple XSLT file (you could just adapt logic to your processor):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- This is just dinamicaly calculated unique sequence of available ids.
    These ids could be just hard-coded if it is suitable for you. -->
    <xsl:key name="level" match="//Level/@id" use="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="levelIds">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Level/@id[generate-id() = generate-id(key('level', .)[1])]">
            <xsl:element name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- List of all Level-s -->
        <xsl:variable name="all-levels" select="//Level"/>

        <!-- Creating result variable with grouped content -->
        <xsl:variable name="grouped-values">

            <!-- Iterating over unique level ids -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$levelIds/id">

                <!-- Creating element for every level -->
                <xsl:variable name="level-id" select="."/>
                <xsl:element name="level">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$level-id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <!-- Extracting and listing appropriate to this level values -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="$all-levels[@id = $level-id]">
                        <xsl:element name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Just testing output for correctness -->
        <xsl:element name="grouped-values">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$grouped-values/level"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see here is grouped output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grouped-values>
   <level id="1">
      <value>com</value>
      <value>com</value>
      <value>com</value>
      <value>com</value>
      <value>com</value>
      <value>com</value>
      <value>com</value>
      <value>com</value>
   </level>
   <level id="2">
      <value>bitstew</value>
      <value>bitstew</value>
      <value>bitstew</value>
      <value>bitstew</value>
      <value>bitstew</value>
      <value>bitstew</value>
      <value>griddirector</value>
      <value>bitstew</value>
   </level>
   <level id="3">
      <value>data</value>
      <value>director-services</value>
      <value>director-services</value>
      <value>director-services</value>
      <value>director-services</value>
      <value>director-services</value>
      <value>director</value>
      <value>adk</value>
   </level>
   <level id="4">
      <value>activity_plan</value>
      <value>manage</value>
      <value>manage</value>
      <value>manage</value>
      <value>manage</value>
      <value>manage</value>
      <value>services</value>
      <value>lib</value>
   </level>
   <level id="5">
      <value>adapters</value>
      <value>adapters</value>
      <value>adapters</value>
      <value>adapters</value>
      <value>adapters</value>
      <value>advanced_search_results</value>
      <value>general_aggregations</value>
   </level>
</grouped-values>
```

So now you can process these `$grouped-values` depends on your needs using simple two nested `<xsl:for-each>` items, e.g.:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$grouped-values/level">
    <xsl:variable name="level" select="."/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$level/value">

        <xsl:element name="value">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="$level/@id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Good luck!